# What are the matrix coefficients associated with the irreducible representations of compact real linear algebraic groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, harmonic-analysis

What are the matrix coefficients associated with the irreducible representations of a compact real linear algebraic group $G$?

Peter-Weyl tells us that $L^2(G)$ is the (closure of) $\bigoplus_\pi A_{\pi}$, where $A_{\pi}$ is the space of matrix coefficients associated with the representation $\pi$, and where $\pi$ runs over the irreducible unitary representations.

I've seen many sources that stop the discussion of Peter-Weyl here. My question is about how to compute this in practice. For a given compact real linear algebraic group, its irreducible (unitary) representations are classified by the theory of the highest weights. My question, therefore, boils down to whether there exists an easy way to compute the matrix coefficients for the irreducible representation associated with some weight.

As an example, how does it manifest in the case of the orthogonal group? What is the associated orthonormal basis for $L^2(G)$?

Comment: A generalised version of this is called a [zonal spherical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonal_spherical_function).

Comment: I'm confused about how that fits in -- it appears to me that zonal spherical functions are about L^2(G/K) where K is maximal compact. I am interested in the G is compact case. How should I be thinking about this?

Comment: When you say "compute the matrix coefficients" of a given irrep $\pi$, what do you mean? Do you mean some explicit parametrization with respect to a given o.n. basis of $H_\pi$? Or some kind of extrinsinc condition of the form "$f\in A_\pi$ if and only if some operator annihilates $f$"?

Comment: I mean giving an orthonormal basis for each $A_{\pi}$.

Comment: In the case where G=SU(2) the irreps have an explicit description as symmetric tensor powers of the "tautological" 2-dim rep $V$. Picking an o.n. basis of the 2-dim space $V$ you can work out what norm to put on $\mathrm{Sym}^k({\mathbb C}^2)$ that makes it a unitary representation of $SU(2)$, and then this gives you an explicit o.n. basis for that irrep. Would this kind of construction be what you are after?

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$ [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378310#comment959885_378310), it's just $K$ compact subgroup.  As the article mentions, the motivating case is $K = \SO(2, \mathbb R)$ inside $G = \SO(3, \mathbb R)$,  Your case is $K = 1$. \\ As to @YemonChoi's [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378310/what-are-the-matrix-coefficients-associated-with-the-irreducible-representations#comment959889_378310), the point is there's obvious ONB for $A_\pi$: matrix coefficients of $v^* \otimes w$ where $v$ and $w$ range over ONB of $\pi$.  What format answer do you want?

Comment: Schur orthogonality relations show that if you have an o.n. basis for each $H_\pi$ then this will give you a family of pairwise orthogonal coefficient functions in $A_\pi$, which can then be rescaled.

Comment: It's somehow still not clear to me how to do that explicitly. Take for example the orthogonal group. I know how to parametrize the irreducible reps via the highest weight, but it's not clear to me what matrix coefficients are associated to each potential highest weight. I guess that the point is that the way that a basis of $H_{\pi}$ yields a basis of $A_{\pi}$ goes through knowing how $\pi(g)$ for any $g\in G$ acts on that basis...

Comment: I agree that it is not enough just to know the highest weight parametrization in order to obtain a basis, but as @LSpice and I have tried to point out, as soon as you have an explicit basis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ for $H_\pi$ then you can write down the corresponding matrix coefficient functions on $G$, namely $\langle \pi( \cdot) v_j, v_i \rangle$. Do you agree that this is enough? If so, then we can reduce your original question to the problem of computing an explicit ONB for each irrep, which I acknowledge is not trivial

Comment: The reason presentations stop after the PW Thm is these things are complicated. For $SU(2)$ or $SO(3)$ see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix  For higher dimension $SO(n)$, you might find formulas in the series of books https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792314660